# Android Studio "failed to resolve" Azure Dependency 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-android:3.1.0'

Tags: android, azure, android-studio, dependencies

I have been trying to resolve this issue for several hours now with no avail.

Basically I am trying to add Azure services to an existing android app - I have setup the Azure end and am at the stage of adding to my project.
The Azure guide says:
For Android Studio, add the following lines to the project’s Gradle.build file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

And add the following to the app’s Gradle.build file with your desired SDK version plugged in (you can find the latest versions here ):

```
compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-android:{version}'
```

I have done the first step without any issues, however the second part is where I am becoming stuck - I am trying to use version 3.1.0 which I know works as it works on the quickstart example Azure provides. 
I have also tried manually downloading the .jar file and putting it in a libs folder in the project but the same error was shown.

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this?
If you need any more information just ask!
Thanks in advance, Jack!

Edit: Trying adding the dependency to each file, I didnt get the same unable to resolve message but the program still says it cannot find my import: import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.*;

Comment: Do you add the dependency to the Module app level build.gradle file? if so, could you provide more detailed information about your problem. I don't encounter any problem with same steps that you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this in the end using the 'import library tool' built into android studio - I am unsure what this is doing differently to manually adding the dependencies as the Azure documentation says to do but its all working as expected now.